# How to force unitary Euclidean norm in a complex matrix by multiplication with a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I need to solve the following problem:

Suppose a non-sparse, non-singular complex matrix $\mathbf{P}$. If I want to force all rows in $\mathbf{P}$ to present unitary Euclidean norms by multiplying $\mathbf{P}$ with a diagonal matrix ($\mathbf{A}$) from the right side (it has to be on the right), such that:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{P} = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
x_1 & 0\\
0 & x_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{P A} =
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
x_1 & 0\\
0 & x_2
\end{array}
\right] = 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
ax_1 & bx_2\\
cx_1 & dx_2
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}

then, the following system must be solved:

\begin{cases}
\left| a \right|^2  x_1^2 + \left| b \right|^2 x_2^2 = 1\\
\left| c \right|^2  x_1^2 + \left| d \right|^2 x_2^2 = 1\\
\end{cases}

In matrix notation

\begin{align}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\left| a \right|^2 & \left| b \right|^2\\
\left| c \right|^2 & \left| d \right|^2
\end{array}
\right]
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1^2\\
x_2^2
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right]\\
\mathbf{T}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1^2\\
x_2^2
\end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{T} = \left| \mathbf{P} \right|^2$, considering $\left| \cdot \right|$ to be element-wise.

The solution for $x_1^2$ and $x_2^2$ is easy to state:

\begin{align}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1^2\\
x_2^2
\end{array}
\right] 
&=
\mathbf{T}^{-1}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right]\\
&= 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
\sum \limits_{j=0}^1 t_{0j}\\
\sum \limits_{j=0}^1 t_{1j}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
where $t_{ij}$ is the element from $\mathbf{T}^{-1}$ in the $i$-th line and $j$-th column.

However, if any of $x_1^2$ or $x_2^2$ happen to be negative, $x_1$ or $x_2$ will be complex and the unitary Euclidean norm fails.

Am I making any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at this would be:
$$
|a|^2 x_1^2 + |b|^2 x_2^2 = 1
$$
is an ellipse. So is the other equation. Now, you have a valid solution when these ellipses intersect in a matching way. Since I am lazy, I used [Wolfram Alpha to do this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+%28x%2C+y%29%3A+a%5E2+%2a+x%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+%2a+y%5E2+%3D+1%2C+c%5E2+%2a+x%5E2+%2B+d%5E2+%2a+y%5E2+%3D+1). In essence, the ellipses must intersect, and the resulting points' coordinates must provide a valid solution for the original system. That is, you may get a solution for an instance where $(x_1, x_2)$ work for $a = 2$, but not for $a = -2$, for example.

The cases where it would not work for any signs of $a, b, c$ and $d$ would be those where the ellipses don't intersect at all.

If someone can come up with a better intuition, I'd be happy to learn.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I would appreciate also if someone can come up with an optimization strategy to find solutions (in case the ellipses don't intersect).

Comment: I don't believe there would exist real solutions if the ellipses don't intersect.